# Dynamic allocating an object

Tags: c++, oop

Here is my code, I was trying to allocate memory to an object by asking size from the user. I dont know where I am going wrong. The error the compiler is giving me is `"void value not ignored as it ought to be"`. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    char name[20];
    char address[30];
    char desig[20];
public:
    void getData();
    void display();
    ~test()
    {
        cout << "Destructor is invoked";
    }
};

void test::getData()
{
    cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter address" << endl;
    cin >> address;

    cout << "Enter designation" << endl;
    cin >> desig;
}

void test::display()
{
    cout << "name" << endl;
    cout << name << endl;

    cout << "address" << endl;
    cout << address;

    cout << "Enter designation" << endl;
    cout << desig;
}

int main()
{

    int s;
    cout << "Enter the size of an array" << endl;
    cin >> s;

    test* p1 = new test[s];

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        *p1[i].getData();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        *p1[i].display();
    }

    delete[] p1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
*p1[i]
```

To:

```
p1[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

`*p1[i].display();`

You're calling member function `display` that returns `void` and try to dereference that.

Comment: +1 Actually the correct answer - to emphasize: *(p1[i].display())